# Velocity Tracker returning different values for android 9.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-api-levels

If I swipe from Right to Left in Samsung S5 or any device lower then 8.0 I get XVelocity in positive numbers and when I swipe right to left in devices greater then 8.0 like android 9 (Note9, s10) for the same swipe I get XVelocity in negative numbers. why it is so ?

```
mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();     
mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity()
```

Comment: just convert to absolute numbers.

Comment: @MartinZeitler can you please explain a little bit?

Comment: there's nothing to explain; it's a primitive math function. absolute means not relative to zero.